# How to verify and replace a cell value in mat table

Tags: angular

I am trying to fill the empty cells in mat table with "0". how can i achieve this using "ngIF". please guide me.

```
  <ng-container >
          <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z2">

            <mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="c">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> data</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.c}}</mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="t1">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{t1}}</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.d1}}</mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="t2">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{t2}}</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.d2}}</mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

            </mat-table>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template expression inside the [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-) `{{ }}` is treated as TS expression. So you could simply do `{{row.d1 || '0'}}`. Try the following

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="c">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Infektpraxis</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.c || '0' }}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here if the `row.c` is undefined, string literal `0` would be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` operator where there is no data like this

`{{row.d2 || "0"}}`

This will check if there is data in `row.d2` and if there isin't it will display `0`

Comment: Can you please stop adding irrelevant tags to Angular questions. This question should not have the html tag - it is not *about* html, it just happens to contain an html example. The question is about Angular, which is why it should just have an Angular tag. If a question contains some Angular code it is not *about* Typescript, unless it contains a specific question about the Typescript language itself.

Comment: Hey @KurtHamilton, I will take care next time, thanks for pointing it out :-)